# Javascript Src Path

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble with the following code within my Index.html file:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="clock.js"></SCRIPT>
```

This works when my `Index.html` file is in the same folder as `clock.js`. Both Index.html and clock.js are in my root folder.

But when my index.html is in these different directories clock.js does not load:

```
/products/index.html
/products/details/index.html
```

What can I put as the 'SRC' so that it will always look for `clock.js` in the root folder?

Comment: **"language" attribute is deprecated**, and "type" one is required (at least, in HTML4.01). You should really change it to - `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 28):

Try:

```
<script src="/clock.js"></script>
```

Note the forward slash.

Answer (score 12):

Use an relative path to the root of your site, for example:

If clock.js is on `http://domain.com/javascript/clock.js`

Include :

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="/javascript/clock.js"></script>
```

If it's on your domain root directory:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="/clock.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not sure "relative path" is the best term for what appears to be an absolute path in your example (in URL vernacular that is).

Comment: Yes, maybe it's not the best term, but when I hear 'absolute path' I think about something more like `http://abc.com/file.js`, maybe *root based path* is a best term, thoughts??

Comment: Yes, I'd probably say root path.  But relative path would be "./file.js".

Answer (score 5):

The common practice is to put scripts in a discrete folder, typically at the root of the site.  So, if clock.js lived here:

```
/js/clock.js
```

then you could add this code to the top of any page in your site and it would just work:

```
<script src="/js/clock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
<script src="/clock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The leading slash means the root directory of your site. Strictly speaking, `language="Javascript"` has been deprecated by `type="text/javascript"`.

Capitalization of tags and attributes is also widely discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

Piece of cake!

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="/clock.js"></SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
src="/clock.js"
```

be careful it's root of the domain.

P.S. and please use lowercase for attribute names.

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
<base href="/" />
```

It's will not load file right. Just delete it.

Answer (score 3):

As you haven't specified, I don't know if you are working with flask (Python), but if you are, you have to put the JavaScript file in a directory called `static`. It should look something like this:

```
/ProjectName
  /static
    clock.js
  /templates
    index.html
  main.py
```

And then refer to the js file as following:

```
<script src="/static/clock.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

As your clock.js is in the root, put your code as this to call your javascript in the index.html found in the folders you mentioned.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="../clock.js"></SCRIPT>
```

This will call the clock.js which you put in the root of your web site.

Comment: This would look in the parent folder of the current folder, and hence would fail.

Comment: @clayRay Depends. Where the OP said they'd put the HTML file as `/products/index.html`, if the JS file were left at the folder above `products`, it would succeed. It would only fail for the `/products/details/index.html` path, because it would reach back to the `products` folder and `clock.js` would still be at the root level (2 folders up, not 1-and therefore would need to be `SRC="../../clock.js"`). I agree it is not ideal and wouldn't work in for all circumstances because of the different paths the OP wants to put their HTML file. But I did want to say it DOES work in 1 situation, at least.