# how to make fullPage.js plugin to work?

Tags: javascript, plugins, fullpage.js

I'm so newbie in javascript ! 
I need your help, guys (pretty please).

I need to initialize fullPage.js plugin into my webpage, but I don't know what is missing. I've read the tutorial for this but I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what.

This is my html code:

```html
<head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/animate.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href='img/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css" /> <!-- fullPage.js plugin -->
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easings.min.js"></script> <!-- fullPage.js plugin -->
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script> <!-- fullPage.js plugin -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery-migrate.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
     anchors: ['first-section', 'second-section', 'third-section', 'fourth-section', 'fifth-section', 'lastPage'],
     scrollingSpeed: 1000
    });
   });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid" id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- fullPage.js plugin -->
</body>
```

Many thanks,

Sandra P.

Comment: You're having `2` jquery js, why ? Plus loading all `js` files in `head` is bad practice. You should load js on DOM after `jquery.min.js` and try to remove `jquery-latest.min.js`. And keep your eye on console logs.

Comment: This is my error from console log: 
(index):25 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullpage is not a function

I don't know how should I write the code to be okay.

Comment: It means `jquery.fullPage.min.js` is not loaded on page load. Please make sure you've the correct path

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411627/javascript-src-path) can help you.

And I recommend to try to replace it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css" /> 
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
```

to this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.min.css" /> 
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
```

This should correct the error `TypeError:. $(...).Fullpage`.
Just look at the live [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/325sL8a4/).

I changed your example and it works, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/9vL3v9ne/2/).

**Update**

Properly include in that order:

1. Styles;
2. jQuery;
3. jQuery Migrate *(I think you do not need it)*;
4. jQuery FullPage and other jQuery
   plugins;
5. you code.

it should look like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="youCSS" /> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<!--other jQuery plugins-->

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="youJS"></script>
```

**Update 2**

Replace youJS :)

```html
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.min.css" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
  anchors : ['first-section', 'second-section', 'third-section', 'fourth-section', 'fifth-section', 'lastPage'],
  scrollingSpeed : 1000
 });
});

 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid" id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
   <div class="row first-section"> Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I guess I'm not sure what order should they have.

Now I have these two errors:

jquery.fullPage.min.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ jquery.fullPage.min.js:8(anonymous function) @ jquery.fullPage.min.js:8
jquery-migrate.min.js:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
(index):23 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullpage is not a function

Comment: can you show me the head tag, please? I can't see it in fiddle,maybe I don't know how to look at it

Comment: @Sandra P. Yes, add to header, and replase this **youCSS** and **youJS** to you code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the errors disappeared, but the fullPage.js plugin still doesn't work :( I don't know what to do now ... what am I missing?

Comment: where did you put this script:
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
  anchors : ['first-section', 'second-section', 'third-section', 'fourth-section', 'fifth-section', 'lastPage'],
  scrollingSpeed : 1000
 });
});

Comment: IT WORKS NOW. Thank you very much.