# jquery only works in html file, not in separate script.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have searched other answers for an resolution to this, but it seemed everyone was simply placing their external .js file *before* the google api jquery link. This, however, is not my case.

html file (named "index.html"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
```

I have this in the body of my html file to create the button:

```
<div class="input">
    <input type="button" id="test" value="CLICK ME" style="width: 500px; height: 100px" />
</div>
```

script file (named "script.js"):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        alert("You clicked it!");
    })
})
```

When I click the button on my site, nothing happens. I have tried multiple configurations of the order for the script file and google api, but nothing else has worked for me.

However, I do know that my script works because when I place my code inside the html file, under the script tag, my code works (the button vanishes and displays the alert). I'm assuming there's a syntax error of some sort in my file linking, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `$(this.hide());` ? You mean `$(this).hide();`

Comment: Could be your `src` path. Check the network console in Chrome and see if the `script.js` file is loading correctly (as opposed to not found). Also, get any console errors? (Note that I am taking your word that it works correctly directly in HTML, obviously what Suresh says is correct, but perhaps that's a typo as you claim it works fine)

Comment: `this` is the DOM element, it has no `hide()` method. You need the jQuery object, so you need `$(this)` instead of `this`

Comment: Ah, that was an error on my part, however I did have that correct a moment ago, I don't know why I changed it. Either way, the external file is still not recognizing my code.

Comment: Okay, just edited it.

Comment: @MattD: Where are you running these files? On a server, or directly from a folder? Where is the script.js file located in related to the html file?

Comment: What errors are you getting in your console?

Comment: [This might be worth a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411627/javascript-src-path) (basically try adding a `/` before `script.js` like this `src="/script.js"`

Comment: That was the issue. That's really strange, just adding a "/". But thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I needed to add a "/" to the path.