# Page with 2 forms, with separate outputs conflicting

Tags: javascript, html

I asked before, but the answer I got didn't fix the issue. I am trying to have a page with at least 2 forms where text entered appears on the output textarea. I want them to operate independent of one another. I have tried to give each one a separate ID as well as giving the output testareas separate ID's. But still is not working. Please help.

```
<form name="Form1" onsubmit="return false;" action="">
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Name:</font></b><br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Phone number:</font></b><br>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone number"><br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Yes/No?:</font></b> <br>   
<select type="drop" name="Question1" id="question1">
<option value="Select Yes or No">...</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Yes/No 2?:</font></b><br>
<select type="drop" name="Question2" id="question2">
<option value="Select Yes, No or n/a">...</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
<option value="n/a">n/a</option>
</select>  
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Notes:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Notes" id="notes" placeholder="Problem" cols="70"  rows="3"></textarea>
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Issue:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Issue" id="issue" placeholder="Issue" cols="70"   rows="6"></textarea>    
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Action:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Action" id="action" placeholder="Action" cols="70"  rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="form1output" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" id="output" cols="70"       rows="25" placeholder="Output"></textarea>
<br>
<div class="btn-group">
<button value="Combine" onclick="convert()">Combine</button> <br><br>
</div>    
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="reset" value="Reset form">Reset form</button> <br><br>
</div>

</form>

<hr>

<form name="Form2" onsubmit="return false;" action="">
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Name:</font></b><br>
<input type="text" name="Name2" id="name2" placeholder="Name"><br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Phone Number:</font></b><br>
<input type="text" name="Currentnumber" id="currentnumber" placeholder="Corrent phone number"><br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Y or N:</font></b> <br>   
<select type="drop" name="YESNO" id="yesno">
<option value="Select Yes or No">...</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Did you offer self serve?:</font></b><br>
<select type="drop" name="Selfserve" id="SSO">
<option value="Select Yes, No or n/a">...</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
<option value="n/a">n/a</option>
</select>  
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Problem:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Problem" id="problem" placeholder="Problem" 
cols="70"  rows="3">               </textarea>
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Issue:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Issue" id="issue2" placeholder="Issue" 
cols="70"   rows="6">                   </textarea>    
<br>
<b><font color="#2C3E60">Action:</font></b><br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="Action" id="action2" placeholder="Action" 
cols="70"   rows="10">     </textarea>
<br>
<textarea type="textarea" name="form2output" id="output2" 
onclick="this.focus();this.select()"                 cols="70" rows="25" 
placeholder="Output"></textarea>
<br>
<div class="btn-group">
<button value="Combine" onclick="convert()">Combine</button> <br><br>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="reset" value="Reset form">Reset form</button> <br><br>
</div>
</form>
```

The first script:

```
<script>
/*Reset command*/
$(document).ready(function(){
$(":reset").css("background-color", "");
});
</script>
<script>
function wordwrap(str, width, brk, cut) {
brk = brk || '\n';
width = width || 60;
cut = cut || false;

if (!str)
return str;

var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : 
'|\\S+?(\\s|$)');

return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join(brk);
}

function convert() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var question1 = document.getElementById("question1").value;
var question2 = document.getElementById("question2").value;
var notes = document.getElementById("notes").value;
var issue = document.getElementById("issue").value;
var action = document.getElementById("action").value;
//input = wordwrap(input, 70, true);

var output = "";

output += "Name: " + name + "\n";
output += "Number: " + phone + "\n";
output += "Question 1?: " + question1 + "\n";
output += "Question 2?: " + question2 + "\n\n";
output += "Notes: " + notes + "\n\n";
output += "Issue: " + issue + "\n\n";
output += "Action: " + action + " ";


document.getElementById("output").value = output;
}


function myFunction(x) {
x.classList.toggle("change");
}
</script>
```

And the second script:

```
<script>
function wordwrap(str, width, brk, cut) {
brk = brk || '\n';
width = width || 60;
cut = cut || false;

if (!str)
return str;

var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : 
'|\\S+?(\\s|$)');

return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join(brk);
}

function convert() {
var Name2 = document.getElementById(name2").value;
var Currentnumber = document.getElementById("currentnumber").value;
var YESNO = document.getElementById("yesno").value;
var selfserve = document.getElementById("SSO").value;
var problem = document.getElementById("problem").value;
var issue2 = document.getElementById("issue2").value;
var action2 = document.getElementById("action2").value;
//input = wordwrap(input, 70, true);

var output = "";

output += "Name2: " + name2 + "\n";
output += "Current number: " + currentnumber + "\n";
output += "Yes No?: " + yesno + "\n";
output += "Self Serve?: " + selfserve + "\n\n";
output += "Problem: " + problem + "\n\n";
output += "Issue: " + issue2 + "\n\n";
output += "Action: " + action2 + " ";


document.getElementById("output2").value = output2;
}

function myFunction(x) {
x.classList.toggle("change");
}

</script>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the problem is that you have two scripts sharing functions with the same names. But using jQuery to its full potential, you can simplify your logic.

(1) For convenience, add an `id` and `type="button"` to your buttons: `id` is to differentiate the buttons shortly and `type="button"` is to prevent the form from submitting by default.

```
<button type="button" id="combine1">Combine</button>

<button type="button" id="combine2">Combine</button>
```

(2) attach an `onclick` event handlers to your buttons

```
$('#combine1').click(function() {
    // get current form
    var button = $(this),
        form = button.closest('form');
    // get field values within current form
    var name = form.find("[name=name]").val(),
        phone = form.find("[name=phone]").val(),
        question1 = form.find("[name=question1]").val(),
        question2 = form.find("[name=question2]").val(),
        notes = form.find("[name=notes]").val(),
        issue = form.find("[name=issue]").val(),
        action = form.find("[name=action]").val();

    var output = "";
        output += "Name: " + name + "\n";
        output += "Number: " + phone + "\n";
        output += "Question 1?: " + question1 + "\n";
        output += "Question 2?: " + question2 + "\n\n";
        output += "Notes: " + notes + "\n\n";
        output += "Issue: " + issue + "\n\n";
        output += "Action: " + action + " ";

    form.find("[name=output]").val(output);
});

// same idea as previous one
$('#combine2').click(function() {
    var button = $(this),
        form = button.closest('form');

    var name = form.find("[name=name]").val(),
        phone = form.find("[name=phone]").val(),
        yesno = form.find("[name=yesno]").val(),
        selfserve = form.find("[name=selfserve]").val(),
        problem = form.find("[name=problem]").val(),
        issue = form.find("[name=issue]").val(),
        action = form.find("[name=action]").val();

    var output = "";
        output += "Name: " + name + "\n";
        output += "Phone: " + phone + "\n";
        output += "Yes No?: " + yesno + "\n";
        output += "Self Serve?: " + selfserve + "\n\n";
        output += "Problem: " + problem + "\n\n";
        output += "Issue: " + issue + "\n\n";
        output += "Action: " + action + " ";

    form.find("[name=output]").val(output);
});
```

**Other notes**

`document.getElementById()` is so passé with jQuery, just use `$(selector)`. There are many variations for `selector` e.g. `#id`, `.class`, `[name=name]`, etc.

Also, you can add [selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) to find elements within an element i.e. `$("[name=name]", form).val()` which is the same as `form.find("[name=name]").val()`.

For illustration purposes, I removed the IDs within your form and some fields share the same name in both forms. The way I different the fields is by using selector context.

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#combine1').click(function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log(this.id);
 
    var button = $(this),
      form = button.closest('form');
      
    var name = form.find("[name=name]").val(),
      phone = form.find("[name=phone]").val(),
      question1 = form.find("[name=question1]").val(),
      question2 = form.find("[name=question2]").val(),
      notes = form.find("[name=notes]").val(),
      issue = form.find("[name=issue]").val(),
      action = form.find("[name=action]").val();

    var output = "";
    output += "Name: " + name + "\n";
    output += "Number: " + phone + "\n";
    output += "Question 1?: " + question1 + "\n";
    output += "Question 2?: " + question2 + "\n\n";
    output += "Notes: " + notes + "\n\n";
    output += "Issue: " + issue + "\n\n";
    output += "Action: " + action + " ";

    form.find("[name=output]").val(output);
  });


  $('#combine2').click(function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log(this.id);
    
    var button = $(this),
      form = button.closest('form');

    var name = form.find("[name=name]").val(),
      phone = form.find("[name=phone]").val(),
      yesno = form.find("[name=yesno]").val(),
      selfserve = form.find("[name=selfserve]").val(),
      problem = form.find("[name=problem]").val(),
      issue = form.find("[name=issue]").val(),
      action = form.find("[name=action]").val();

    var output = "";
    output += "Name: " + name + "\n";
    output += "Phone: " + phone + "\n";
    output += "Yes No?: " + yesno + "\n";
    output += "Self Serve?: " + selfserve + "\n\n";
    output += "Problem: " + problem + "\n\n";
    output += "Issue: " + issue + "\n\n";
    output += "Action: " + action + " ";

    form.find("[name=output]").val(output);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- FORM 1 -->
<form name="Form1" action="">
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Name:</font></b><br>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Phone number:</font></b><br>
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number"><br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Yes/No?:</font></b> <br>
  <select type="drop" name="question1">
        <option value="Select Yes or No">...</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
  <br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Yes/No 2?:</font></b><br>
  <select type="drop" name="question2">
        <option value="Select Yes, No or n/a">...</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="n/a">n/a</option>
    </select>
  <br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Notes:</font></b><br>
  <textarea type="textarea" name="notes" placeholder="Problem" cols="70" rows="3"></textarea>
  <br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Issue:</font></b><br>
  <textarea type="textarea" name="issue" placeholder="Issue" cols="70" rows="6"></textarea>
  <br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Action:</font></b><br>
  <textarea type="textarea" name="action" placeholder="Action" cols="70" rows="10"></textarea>
  <br>
  <textarea type="textarea" name="output" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" cols="70" rows="25" placeholder="Output"></textarea>
  <br>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="combine1">Combine</button> <br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="reset" value="Reset form">Reset form</button> <br><br>
  </div>
</form>

<hr>

<!-- FORM 2 -->
<form name="Form2" action="">
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Name:</font></b><br>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Phone Number:</font></b><br>
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Corrent phone number"><br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Y or N:</font></b> <br>
  <select name="yesno">
        <option value="Select Yes or No">...</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
  <br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Did you offer self serve?:</font></b><br>
  <select name="selfserve">
        <option value="Select Yes, No or n/a">...</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="n/a">n/a</option>
    </select>
  <br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Problem:</font></b><br>
  <textarea type="textarea" name="problem" placeholder="Problem" cols="70" rows="3">               </textarea>
  <br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Issue:</font></b><br>
  <textarea type="textarea" name="issue" placeholder="Issue" cols="70" rows="6">                   </textarea>
  <br>
  <b><font color="#2C3E60">Action:</font></b><br>
  <textarea type="textarea" name="action" placeholder="Action" cols="70" rows="10">     </textarea>
  <br>
  <textarea type="textarea" name="output" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" cols="70" rows="25" placeholder="Output"></textarea>
  <br>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="combine2">Combine</button> <br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="reset" value="Reset form">Reset form</button> <br><br>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. I'll admit I don't understand all of it. Such a JQuery. But I am interested to learn more. And your example works perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @TyH You'll get the hang of it soon enough. Kindly mark it as answered.

Comment: Also, I should have stated, I need this to all work from within a single page, without references to another page, which this seems to. Is there a solution I can use within the same page?

Comment: @TyH My demo is one page.

Comment: It is, but it references https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js  in the script. I assume this would mean if I was trying to use my form when without an internet connection, it would not work correct? Basically I just need a solution using code all on the single page. Is that possible?

Comment: @TyH Using jQuery requires including a file using `<script/>` tag. If you download and include the file relatively, similar to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411649/1022914), then it will work without internet connection. If you can't do that, then you shouldn't be using jQuery in the first place.

Comment: That's what I am asking. How can I do it with just javascript on the single page?I hate be a pain here by asking, I really appreciate the help you have already given. It was my fault for not clarifying all on one page at the beginning.