# JavaScript in HTML not working - onclick=function() + inner.HTML

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, innerhtml

I would like a random sentence (selected through a function) to appear on my HTML when we click on a button.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<button onclick="riddle()">Riddle</button>
<p id="Riddle"> </p>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
function riddle(){
  const randomRiddle = riddlesBase[Math.floor(Math.random()*20)];
  document.getElementById("Riddle").innerHTML = randomRiddle;
};
```

If I console.log(randomRiddle), a sentence appears (a different one each time, but it doesn't do anything on the website here.

Could you tell me what is wrong and how to make it work?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Working in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtsoj76z/)

```js
const riddlesBase = [
'riddle1',
'riddle2',
'riddle3',
'riddle4',
'riddle5',
'riddle6',
'riddle7',
'riddle8',
'riddle9',
'riddle10',
'riddle11',
'riddle12',
'riddle13',
'riddle14',
'riddle15',
'riddle16',
'riddle17',
'riddle18',
'riddle19',
'riddle20',
]

function riddle(){
  const randomRiddle = riddlesBase[Math.round(Math.random()* (riddlesBase.length - 1))];
  document.getElementById("Riddle").innerHTML = randomRiddle;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="riddle()">Riddle</button>
    <p id="Riddle"> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

What does your full HTML look like?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is what my full HTML look like : 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
             <meta charset="UTF-8">
             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
             <script src="riddle.js"></script>
             <title>Riddle</title>
       </head>
       <body>
            <h1>A riddle a day</h1>
            <p>Click on the button below to discover your riddle of the day</p>
            <button onclick="riddle()">Riddle</button>
            <p id="Riddle"> </p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first time posting and commenting and I have no idea how to format the comment to make it more readable.

Comment: I tried with the js directly on html and it works. I'm probably badly linking the js to the html.

Comment: It could be the linking. What does your folder structure "look" like? Generally web apps link javascript files from a different folder from where the html files are located. If you have done that here, you will need to add the path to the javascript file relative to your html file. Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411627/javascript-src-path

Comment: Oh so this is the problem. Never knew that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no issues. Check with this code and try again.This one works properly.

```
   `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Javascript Events</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script>
          const riddlesBase = [
            "Riddle 1",
            "Riddle 2",
            "Riddle 3",
            "Riddle 4",
            "Riddle 5",
            "Riddle 6",
            "Riddle 7",
            "Riddle 8",
            "Riddle 9",
            "Riddle 10",
            "Riddle 11",
            "Riddle 12",
            "Riddle 13",
            "Riddle 14",
            "Riddle 15",
            "Riddle 16",
            "Riddle 17",
            "Riddle 18",
            "Riddle 19",
            "Riddle 20",
          ];
    
          function riddle() {
            const randomRiddle = riddlesBase[Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)];
            document.getElementById("Riddle").innerHTML = randomRiddle;
            console.log(randomRiddle);
          }
        </script>
        <button onclick="riddle()">Riddle</button>
        <p id="Riddle"></p>
      </body>
    </html>`
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This code does work on my side. I'll try to add my code on the html and not link the js to html.